# HTML how to add margin-bottom to nested list

Tags: html, css

I have a html markup below which is consisted of nested list:

I have added a css rule for `<li>` element to have margin bottom.

I just realised that the rule does not seem to apply for the nested portion of the list.

I open a `<ol>` element inside a `<li>` and the margin bottom does not seem to apply inside there.

In my example it is the text between 'point 3' and 'point a' . As shown in the picture below:

[image]

code is below:

```css
li{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
v<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->
<ol>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
</ol>
<p>simplifying the means for</p>
<ol start="3">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>disposable cpatial</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any advice.

Comment: `li>ol{
  margin-top:10px;
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution, using `margin-top` on the sub-lists (`ul`, `ol`). In this solution a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` with `1em` is set. So the space between the lists is equal:

```css
li > ol,
li > ul {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
    </ol>
    <p>simplifying the means for</p>
    <ol start="3">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.
        <ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha;">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.
            <ol style="list-style-type: lower-roman;">
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam velit arcu, ultrices sit amet scelerisque nec, consequat in nisi. Pellentesque maximus, massa id accumsan pretium, velit lacus sollicitudin velit, ut feugiat erat sem eu erat. Morbi ut rutrum purus, ut suscipit sapien. Fusce id leo vehicula, egestas libero eget, gravida sem. Praesent nunc tortor, pellentesque at ligula ut, bibendum cursus magna. Quisque sit amet arcu lobortis, consectetur tellus ac, dictum sem. Sed rutrum sit amet ipsum sit amet porttitor. Aliquam viverra interdum nisl, id luctus mauris molestie nec. Proin auctor felis eu tortor luctus, at ultricies lacus scelerisque.</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>disposable cpatial</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```